# Python regex: find words and emoticons

Tags: python, regex, emoticons

I want to find matches between a tweet and a list of strings containing words, phrases, and emoticons. Here is my code:

`words = [':)','and i','sleeping','... :)','! <3','facebook']
regex = re.compile(r'\b%s\b|(:\(|:\))+' % '\\b|\\b'.join(words), flags=re.IGNORECASE)`

I keep receiving this error:

`error: unbalanced parenthesis`

Apparently there is something wrong with the code and it cannot match emoticons. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The parentheses in `words` are not escaped.

Comment: please let me know how to fix it @Nicarus

Comment: Try escaping them.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The re module has a function `escape` that takes care of correct escaping of words, so you could just use

`words = map(re.escape, [':)','and i','sleeping','... :)','! <3','facebook'])`

Note that word boundaries might not work as you expect when used with words that don't start or end with actual word characters.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the below and it stopped throwing the error:

```
words = [':\)','and i','sleeping','... :\)','! <3','facebook']
```

Answer (score 1):

While `words` has all the necessary formatting, re uses `(` and `)` as special characters. This requires you to use `\(` or `\)` to avoid them being interpreted as special characters, but rather as the ASCII characters 40 and 41. Since you didn't understand what @Nicarus was saying, you need to use this:

```
words = [':\)','and i','sleeping','... :\)','! <3','facebook']
```

Note: I'm only spelling it out because this doesn't seem like a school assignment, for all the people who might want to criticize this. Also, look at the documentation prior to going to stack overflow. [This](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) explains everything.