# Python regex raises the "nothing to repeat" error

Tags: python, regex

I found couple of other posts talking about this issue, but still couldn't find out how to fix mine. Here is my code:

```
words = [':\)','sleeping','... :\(','facebook','tired','out of the',"i'm"]
regex = re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % '\\b|\\b'.join(words), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

I get this error:

```
error: nothing to repeat
```

Comment: Your `words` list is not declared properly.

Comment: the regex re.compile line looks fine to me

Comment: How should I fix it? @RohanAmrute

Comment: I did not get any error in `re.compile`.  it looks fine. Check once again

Comment: Where are you getting the error? Including the stack trace would help deduce if it's happening in your regex or somewhere else.

Comment: Please also note that `.` matches everything except newlines, not just a literal dot. Use `re.escape` as I suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40645173/python-regex-find-words-and-emoticons

Comment: It's not a whole list of words. It's length is 1600. @RohanAmrute

Comment: looks like the source of error might coming from the long list of words

Comment: Many thanks. It worked beautifully @SebastianProske

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two possibilities. Either you are running into a Python bug related to your regular expression, or you have an unescaped set of `()` inside your list. Either way, making sure that you're not accidentally matching regex pattern would probably be wise.

Have you tried this instead?

```
escaped = map(re.escape, words)
re.compile(r'\b%s\b' % '\\b|\\b'.join(escaped), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

All of that said, if your list really does have 1,600 elements, then perhaps regular expression isn't the best task for the job.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this solution and it worked pretty nice